# How to get the value of propetry and set payload in proxy wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Here is my proxy code:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ProviderPublication" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
  <inSequence>
     <filter xmlns:p="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/" xpath="//p:OpenPublicationSession">
        <then>
           <property xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/" name="ChannelURI" expression="//xs:ChannelURI" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
           <class name="wso2.org.Communicator.OpenPublication">
              <property name="channelURI" value="myChannelURI"/>
           </class>
           **<property name="sessionIDFromClassMediator" expression="get-property('SessionID')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>**
           <header name="To" action="remove"/>
           <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
           <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
           <payloadFactory>
              <format>
                 <ns1:OpenPublicationSessionResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/">
                    <ns1:SessionID>$1</ns1:SessionID>
                 </ns1:OpenPublicationSessionResponse>
              </format>
              <args>
                 <arg expression="get-property('sessionIDFromClassMediator')"/>
              </args>
           </payloadFactory>
           <send/>
        </then>
        <else>
           <filter xpath="//p:PostPublication">
              <then>
                 <property xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/" name="SessionID" expression="//xs:SessionID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                 <property xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/" name="Topic" expression="//xs:Topic" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                 <property xmlns:xs="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/" name="Expiry" expression="//xs:Expiry" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                 <property xmlns:ns="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/" name="MessageContent" expression="//MessageContent" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                 <class name="wso2.org.postPublication.PostPublication">
                    <property name="topic" value="Sports"/>
                    <property name="sessionID" value="session_001"/>
                    <property name="messagecontent" value="Cricket on air"/>
                    <property name="expiry" value="Monday"/>
                 </class>
                 <property name="getMessageIDFromClassMed" expression="get-property('MessageID')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                 <log level="full">
                    **<property name="SessionIDFromFstFltr" expression="get-property('sessionIDFromClassMediator')"/>**
                 </log>
```

I AM NOT ABLE TO GET THE PROPERTY VALUE OF sessionIDFromClassMediator SO MY FILTER NEVER GETS TRUE AND CAN'T GET INSIDE THE FILTER

```
                 **<filter xpath="get-property('sessionIDFromClassMediator') = get-property('SessionID')">
                    <then>
                       <log level="custom">
                          <property name="STATE" value="message is sent to queue"/>
                       </log>
                       <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                       <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                       <header name="To" action="remove"/>
                       <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                       <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
                       <payloadFactory>
                          <format>
                             <ns1:PostPublicationResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/">
                                <ns1:MessageID>$1</ns1:MessageID>
                             </ns1:PostPublicationResponse>
                          </format>
                          <args>
                             <arg expression="get-property('getMessageIDFromClassMed')"/>
                          </args>
                       </payloadFactory>
                       <send/>
                    </then>
                    <else>
                       <log level="full">
                          <property name="FilterNotRunning" value="----------FilterNotRunning------------------"/>
                       </log>
                       <drop/>
                    </else>
                 </filter>**
              </then>
              <else>
                 <drop/>
              </else>
           </filter>
        </else>
     </filter>
  </inSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="jms:/myQueue?&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
  </endpoint>
```

So i want to get the value of `<property name="sessionIDFromClassMediator" expression="get-property('SessionID')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>` so that i can use this property value to match with Other Property after

```
<class name="wso2.org.postPublication.PostPublication">
                            <property name="topic" value="Sports"/>
                            <property name="sessionID" value="session_001"/>
                            <property name="messagecontent" value="Cricket on air"/>
                            <property name="expiry" value="Monday"/>
                         </class>
```

and after that i am sending message to Message broker but before that i want to associate a payload which should be send to the queue of message broker. I want to implement payload inside

I AM NOT ABLE TO GET THE PROPERTY VALUE OF sessionIDFromClassMediator SO MY FILTER NEVER GETS TRUE AND CAN'T GET INSIDE THE FILTER

```
 **<filter xpath="get-property('sessionIDFromClassMediator') = get-property('SessionID')">
                        <then>
                           <log level="custom">
                              <property name="STATE" value="message is sent to queue"/>
                           </log>
                           <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                           <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                           <header name="To" action="remove"/>
                           <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                           <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
                           <payloadFactory>
                              <format>
                                 <ns1:PostPublicationResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/">
                                    <ns1:MessageID>$1</ns1:MessageID>
                                 </ns1:PostPublicationResponse>
                              </format>
                              <args>
                                 <arg expression="get-property('getMessageIDFromClassMed')"/>
                              </args>
                           </payloadFactory>
                           <send/>
                        </then>
                        <else>
                           <log level="full">
                              <property name="FilterNotRunning" value="----------FilterNotRunning------------------"/>
                           </log>
                           <drop/>
                        </else>
                     </filter>**
```

part.THE MAIN PROBLEM IS THAT THE FIRST FILTER IS EXECUTED WHEN I ENVOKE OPERATION OPENPUBLICATION, AND WHEN I ENVOKE THE SECOND OPERATION ALL THE PROPERTY VALUE GET RESET. SO HOW CAN I MAKE PROPERTY VALUE PERSISTENT SO THAT IT IS NEVER LOST?  Hope you understand my question and looking forward to your solutions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add some logs of your property to see if it is there or not:

```
<log level="custom">
   <property name="your property" expression="get-property('sessionIDFromClassMediator'))"/>
</log>
```

Keep in mind the different [levels of the properties (transport, axis2, axis2-client).](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Property+Mediator)

I also had quite some problems with the [filter mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Filter+Mediator) using the xpath attribute. I don't use it anymore and always use the combination of "source" and "regex".

Example:

```
<filter source="$body/anElementInTheBody" regex="true">
```

So for your case you can create an additional property (just before the filter) that will contain the boolean value if it should be filtered or not. Then with the regex=true you will enter the filter.

This is just a pseudo code of your example - maybe need some corrections:

```
<property name="filterCondition" expression="get-property('sessionIDFromClassMediator') = get-property('SessionID')"/>
<filter source="get-property('filterCondition')" regex="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked for me. But again i have a problem. request that i am sending via try-it tool, i want to send that request to Message Broker's queue, but instead of request the response is getting passed to queue.<log level="custom">
                              <property name="STATE" value="message is sent to queue"/>
                           </log>.This is the code to send data to queue
                           <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
                           <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>

Comment: You want to change the payload and then send to a JMS queue?

Comment: no. I want to send the request to a jms queue that i am passing when invoking the proxy service through try-it tool and want to show the response as written in above code as well through the payload. In short the request should go to jms queue and response should be <ns1:PostPublicationResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/">
                                    <ns1:MessageID>$1</ns1:MessageID>
                                 </ns1:PostPublicationResponse>
specified in payload

Comment: so remove the "OUT_ONLY" in the inSequence and then create the outSequence. There you should get your response from the jms

Comment: no you still dont get my question. I want to send the request body to jms queue and and am making custom response using payload in above code, that i want to show to end user

Comment: How can i check if a property value is null or empty?